# Are these sentences correct/meaningful?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

1. Ignore this word, it's a *delenda*.
2. I'm going to remove this *delenda* later.
3. Should we mark this word as *delenda*?

Comment: Well, "delenda" is plural, so your examples don't really fit.

Comment: so is it enough to conjugate/decline verbs and adjectives and it would make sense? I encourage you to answer more exhaustively, I will mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: No one knows what "delenda" means, so it's probably better to not use the word.

Comment: -1? isn't this platform meant to learn? is one not allowed to make mistakes?

Comment: what's better would be writing a constructive answer, not a salty comment.

Comment: Questions should be based on meaningful examples. These sentences are incorrect, and quickly checking in an online dictionary (which is expected on ELU in such cases) will show why.

Comment: So you answer only if the sentences are correct? And what's your added value then?

Comment: We answered your question.  What more do you want??

Comment: Back to square one. You're new on the site, so you don't know all the rules. Your first step should be to look this up in a dictionary. Perhaps you did, and are now curious about how to use the word _delenda_. If you did, you should say so and explain why you still don't understand it. So you should try to do that next time. All that said, I can see why you ask the question. Since _delenda_ is always plural, your first two sentences don't work. You can't have "a" or "this" _delenda_. I'm not sure, but I believe you could arguably use sentence 3, as it refers to _delenda_ as a larger category.

Comment: @IsabelArcher thanks for your comment, I appreciate it. As suggested in the "This question is off-topic" hint which appeared today, it is probably better to use [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) for this kind of questions. I am learning a new English word everyday, and some words raise a doubt that I need to clear.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your comments/feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Wiktionary defines delenda as items to be deleted.

https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/delenda#Noun

Comment: Good point, thanks, I've missed that it is plural only.